# Java / PriorityQueue and Threads

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, priority-queue

In my application I have 4 threads adding elements to a `PriorityBlockingQueue` and one thread polling elements out of it. For the polling thread the queue seems to be not accessible. I assume I have to take measures to make it thread safe.

After I take the first element I clear the queue, it should be filled up again by the other 4 filling threads.

The polling and filling threads are inside the same class which holds the `PriorityBlockingQueue`.

That's the code for the polling one:

```
private class UPPainter implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(queue.size() > 0) {
            ReceivedMsg msg = queue.poll();
            queue.clear();
            for(final IPacketListener c : listeners) {
                new Thread(new ListenerUp(c, msg)).start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Err.. why are you polling a PriorityBlockingQueue with no actual blocking?  Why are you clearing it after receiving one element?  This code is a bit...strange.

Comment: I get packets with 10Hz frequency but can't process them at these frequency, so I store them in the queue to get them compared and just poll the important one. After getting one it will be processed (takes 2 seconds) and I clear the queue (will be filled up by the other threads again) ... how blocking should be done, that's the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your consumer threads start, the queue is possibly empty, so size = 0 and run() will exit.
You have to actually wait for a msg to be entered.
Also clearing the queue doesn't seem to make sense to me?
If you want to "close" the consumer threads, send a special end-of-queue message.
Use queue.take() to actually block until an element is inserted:

```
private class UPPainter implements Runnable {  
    @Override  
    public void run() {  
        while(true) {  
            ReceivedMsg msg = queue.take();  
            for(final IPacketListener c : listeners) {  
                new Thread(new ListenerUp(c, msg)).start();  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Oh no, it seems the you are right and the if-clause made the difference. I clear the queue because it is filled up much faster than it is taken from it (and during the processing of the messages which is done via `new Thread(new ListenerUp(c, msg)).start()` I do not need to store the "old" messages in the queue.

Comment: hmm, then you won't need the loop at all. Simple queue.take();queue.clear();